# Unable to create hive table with constraints in Hive 2.3.0

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am unable to create table with constraints just like primary key or not null. Without constraints I can create table sucessfully.

I found that Hive support primary keys/foreign keys constraint as part of create table command in 2.1.0 and my version is 2.3.0. Following is the example code:

```
create table test3(a int primary key)
```

and this returns me the following error message:

```
MismatchedTokenException(221!=347)
    at org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.recoverFromMismatchedToken(BaseRecognizer.java:617)
    at org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.match(BaseRecognizer.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.createTableStatement(HiveParser.java:6179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.ddlStatement(HiveParser.java:3808)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:2382)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1333)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:204)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseUtils.parse(ParseUtils.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseUtils.parse(ParseUtils.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:468)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1316)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:184)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:403)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:821)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:686)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
FAILED: ParseException line 1:25 mismatched input 'primary' expecting ) near 'int' in create table statement
```

I am using Hive 2.3.0 and Hadoop 2.7.3.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create the PRIMARY KEY using the below command

```
CREATE TABLE TEST3(A INT
  PRIMARY KEY(A) disable novalidate);
```

Since these constraints are not validated, an upstream system needs to ensure data integrity before it is loaded into Hive.